# Apache will not deliver resources in sub directories of /var/www/html

Tags: image, apache

I currently have a server running Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2. I am not able to access png's and svg files in sub directories. Example: /var/www/html/icons/new.svg when the page is located in /var/www/html/index.php. However, Apache will deliver images from within the page directory so all photos within /var/www/html will be delivered.

The error code for the images is just a plain 404. I am able to access pages within /var/www/html/sub/index.php. All images are using relative links if that matters.

I do have a non verified ssl on my server but even on plain http it doesn't deliver if that matters.

It's probably a dumb question but thanks for your time anyways.

All Code worked on a local wamp server before being put on a lamp server.

Example Code:

```
<img src="icons/new.svg"> <!--Wont work-->
<img src="logo.svg"> <!--Will Work-->
```

Inside /var/www/html

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root   4096 Jun 26 18:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jun 22 18:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Jun 26 17:50 icons
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4340 Jun 26 18:11 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4172 Jun 26 18:11 logo.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1856 Jun 26 18:11 mainstyle.css
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 26 17:50 PHP
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 26 17:50 plandetails
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 26 17:50 planicons
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 295915 Jun 26 18:11 searchbkg.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7366 Jun 26 18:11 searchbkg.svg
```

Inside the icons folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun 26 17:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 26 18:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  446 Jun 26 18:37 arrowleft.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  446 Jun 26 18:37 arrowrt.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7863 Jun 26 18:37 bestoffer.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4024 Jun 26 18:37 free.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  477 Jun 26 18:37 informationbubble.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3404 Jun 26 18:37 new.svg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 26 17:50 plans
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 26 17:50 prices
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2272 Jun 26 18:37 save.svg
```

Updated /var/www/html perms

```
   drwxr-xr-x 6 root root   4096 Jun 26 18:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jun 22 18:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Jun 26 17:50 icons
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4340 Jun 26 18:37 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4172 Jun 26 18:37 logo.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1856 Jun 26 18:37 mainstyle.css
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 26 17:50 PHP
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 26 17:50 plandetails
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 26 17:50 planicons
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 295915 Jun 26 18:37 searchbkg.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7366 Jun 26 18:37 searchbkg.svg
```

**For anyone wondering I used the combination of the help below and [this](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003364874-All-requests-containing-icons-are-redirected-to-the-usr-share-httpd-icons-or-to-usr-share-apache2-icons-folder)**

Comment: Let's see some code. I have a feeling this is a path issue.

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: what does `ls -la /var/www/html` output?

Comment: Added it to the code section.Also all the links in the inspect element seem to be pointing to where the files exist.

Comment: can i see the inside the icons folder ?

Comment: Sure I added it in too.

Comment: ok go to your url `localhost/your_site/icons` do you get the 404 error?

Comment: I got a 403 error now

Comment: that's mean folder is ok. but forbidden. now go to `localhost/your_site/icons/new.svg`

Comment: if it's says 403 run these two commands
`find  /var/www/html -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755
`find  /var/www/html -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644`

Comment: Look at your Apache logfiles, they will show what is wrong.

Comment: I suggest you test to see if it's a permission issue by running `chmod -R 0777 var/www/html`. If your site works then you have a permission issue on your files/dirs, if it doesn't then your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah it still didn't work after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a php question, this is an apache question and is a matter of permissions, try:

```
chmod a+rx /var/www/html/sub/
```

and

```
chmod a+r /var/www/html/*
```

EDIT:

Your Virtual Host should be:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory /var/www/html>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I tried this and now I am not able to access /var/www/html/index.php.You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: It's because you don't have permissions to access this file, please send the ls -la output

Comment: I got the index page to work by configuring the apache <Directory /> to allow all but the images are still not being delivered to the person who views the webpage. I added the code in the post because it didnt format good here.

Comment: did you added a new directory for the app "sub" in httpd.conf?

Comment: Not specifically but it should be covered in /var/www/ as there are multiple folders like /var/www/html/PHP and /var/www/html/icons

Comment: just like bassxzero said, is a path issue, check DocumentRoot path, it should be /var/www/html and Directory also should be set /var/www/html

Comment: Yeah they both are.

Comment: what about the apache log?, if you access, do you still get the 403 Error?

Comment: I have a couple of thoughts. did you created a .conf file for the app?, did you enabled the site? or are you treating the sub folder and part of the app tree to retrieve assets?, if so, so the folder/s have the correct permissions either to USER as for the GROUP?

Comment: I believe the error is for when i tried to access /var/www/html/icons/. And Apparently it's attempting to serve /user/share/apache2/icons/ when it should be /var/www/html/icons/. But it also says No matching DirectoryIndex because in the icons folder there is no page to be loaded just .svgs

Comment: Yeah I am just trying to retrieve .svg files from the sub directory theres no .php files to load.

Comment: It's your VirtualHost settings, it is looking for apache root folder instead of the web folder. add this to  a .htaccess `AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz` `AddEncoding gzip svgz`